# (ObjectBox) Gson doesn't parse from 'JSON to entity' which contains a ToOne relation object

Tags: android, gson, greendao, objectbox

My Entity is as follows.

```
@Entity
public class Conference {

@Id(assignable = true)
public long conferenceID;
public ToOne<ConferenceAgenda> agenda;

}
```

ConferenceAgenda Class as follows

```
@Entity
public class ConferenceAgenda {

@Id
public long id;
public ToMany<ConferenceAgendaDay> days;
}
```

Here is my ConferenceAgendaDay.class

```
@Entity
public class ConferenceAgendaDay {

@Id
public long id;
public String title;
}
```

I am getting a JSON response from server as

```
{"conferenceID":2,"agenda":{"days":[{"title":"day-1"}]}}
```

I am trying to parse the above JSON to the entity. "conferenceID" is getting parsed but the "agenda"
doesn't get parsed. Am I doing something wrong or is there any other way I can parse the JSON.

objectboxVersion : 1.1.0

Comment: What does your ConferenceAgenda type contain?

Comment: Hi @KobusPitzer Added the conferenceAgenda class too.

Comment: Can you add the ConferenceAgendaDay class as well? I haven't used the "ToMany" but there is only one "days" object and it has an array of data possibly, shouldn't that be "ToOne" as well?

Comment: @KobusPitzer Added the ConferenceAgendaDay class too. thanks

Comment: @KobusPitzer  Its an array, But in the JSON there is having only one item in the array. And the toOne and ToMany are relational objects used in GreenDao's ObjectBox library.

Comment: Ah yes I see, sorry. Will have to look at that